# Octave smooth curve graph

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I want to draw a smooth curve fit graph in Octave on my data instead of sharp line just like scatter with smooth line in Excel.

My data as as follows:

```
x = [1, 2 , 3];
y = [53, 48, 31];
y1 = [89, 51, 49];
```

When i do a normal plot it gives linear graph with sharp edges on a point. I want smooth graph. How can i plot that in Octave. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, you only have 3 data points, so of course your graph is not going to be "smooth". Get (much) more data points, and you will have a "smooth" graph, provided your data is "smooth".

You can also fit a "smooth" curve to your data, but that's a different question entirely, plus you will also need more data points for a meaningful fit.

Answer (score 1):

Very old, but might still be useful. Do e.g.

```
x = [1, 2 , 3];
y = [53, 48, 31];
y1 = [89, 51, 49];
xspline = linspace(min(x),max(x),100);
yspline = interp1(x,y,xspline,"pchip");
yspline1 = interp1(x,y1,xspline,"pchip");
plot(xspline,yspline,xspline,yspline1);
```

You can find different interpolation "smoothing" methods by entering

```
help interp1
```

in the example above

```
"pchip"
      Piecewise cubic Hermite interpolating
      polynomial--shape-preserving interpolation with smooth first
      derivative.
```

is used.